# Обновить Itemcontrol.ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется листбокс и ItemControl (shopControl).
При нажатии на листбокс я получаю название нажатого элемента (title). В shopControl расположена коллекция элементов

```
Elements = new ObservableCollection<ShopItem>();
```

Когда название элемента получено - я сравниваю все элементы, оставляю только те, которые содержат (title), остальное удаляю.

```
var list = (ListBox)sender;
        TodoItem catTitle = (TodoItem)list.SelectedItem;
        string title = catTitle.Title.ToLower();

        for (int n = Elements.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
        {
            if (!Elements[n].Slot.Contains(title))
            {
                Elements.RemoveAt(n);
            }
        }
```

При повторном выборе элемента в листбоксе - пропадают все остальные элементы (т.к. остальные были удалены изначально) и я получаю пустой контрол. Каким образом скрыть лишние элементы без удаления, и отобразить только нужные мне?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте ICollectionView

```
private List<MyModel> _myList = new List<MyModel>();
 public ICollectionView MyList
 {
     get { return _myList; }
     set { _myList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyList"); }
 }
```

В конструкторе

```
MyList.Filter = FilterTask;
```

Создайте метод для фильтрации

```
 public bool FilterTask(object value)
 {
    var entry = value as MyModel;
    return entry != null && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filterString) || entry.DisplayName.Contains(_filterString));
 }
```

Свойства для фильтра

```
private string _filterString = string.Empty;
public string FilterString
{
   get { return _filterString; }
   set
   {
      _filterString = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterString");
      _myList?.Refresh();
   }
}
```

Xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>         
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList, Mode=OneWay}">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}"/>     
</DataGrid>
```

Уведомляем об изменении свойства

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
 {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
 }
```

Comment: Я вообще ничего не поняла( Вы не могли бы сделать это на моем примере?..  Мой код в xaml  `<ItemsControl x:Name="shopControl" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Elements...`, я уже заранее подгружаю из xml объекты, разбираю на составляющие и через ObservableCollection добавляю их.  Что касается листбокса, при нажатии на который я сортирую итемы по названию в листбоксе => до Elements.Slot слова, сравниваю названия удаляю, если не относится к категории..  Что мне делать в этом случае?

Comment: Я же вам все написал. просто оберните ваш список Elements в ICollectionView и фильтруйте его не удаляя елементов. Можете написать так  _myFilteredView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Elements);

Comment: Так и не поняла...  отсутствует NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterString");,  _myList?.Refresh(); ошибка в точке и требует после Refresh() поставить двоеточие,  и куча других ошибок. В добавок я использую другой тип коллекции для прочих методов...

Comment: Добавил NotifyPropertyChanged в ответ. _myList?.Refresh(); знак вопроса, это синтаксис c# 6.0 т.е. проверка на null можно заменить на if(_myList!=null) _myList.Refresh();